# Jquery 'on' event with .bind(this). How to access $(this)?

Tags: javascript

I register an event

```
$('button').on('click', this.method.bind(this));

master.prototype.method = function() {
  // This works only if i bind(this) in the event.
  this.otherMethod();

  // The jquery $(this) does not work more...
  $(this).addClass('...');
}


// But that does not work: (I will reference to the 'button')
$(this).addClass('class');
```

How can I access the right `button` element without $(this)? Or can i access $(this) within my method?

Comment: Please add a complete example, rather than three unrelated snippets in the same code block. It's impossible to tell what you're doing.

Comment: `$('button').on('click', function () { this.method.bind(this) });` ??

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: That wouldn't work.

Comment: @FelixKling But the question is not clear (before the author edit), I understand that he wants to access after the click. So it makes sense within what is possible to understand the question (before the author edit).

Comment: @FelixKling I think I understand, `this.method` into `function` don't make sense, it was at the time of hurry.  :) Sorry

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: Yep :)

Answer (score 2):

`this.method` will get the Event object passed as first argument. If you define the function to have a parameter `event`, you can reference the element via [**`event.target`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).